# Could not get file path not located in project

Tags: c#, winforms, system.io.directory, system.io.file

I have a Problem with my program. I want to make a application like Window Explore and When I double-click to an item in ListView it will show file/folder dept in it. I use this code `Path.GetFullPath(fileName)` to find the full path of the selected item name but It always return my current project path. I couldn't find anyway to resolve it. Does anyone know please help me! Thanks so much! Here is my code:

```
        private void listViewFolder_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.listViewFolder.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            ListView temp = (ListView)sender;
            string fileName = ((ListViewItem)temp.SelectedItems[0]).Text;

            string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

            this.listViewFolder.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo _nodeDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] _subFolder;
            ListViewItem _item = null;
            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo i in _nodeDirectory.GetDirectories())
                {
                    _item = new ListViewItem(i.Name, 1);
                    _subFolder = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(_item, "Directory") };
                    this.listViewFolder.Items.Add(_item);
                }
                foreach (FileInfo file in _nodeDirectory.GetFiles())
                {
                    _item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 2);
                    _subFolder = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(_item, "File") };
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Folder Access denied", ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a headache and place the full path in the item.Tag property. You can then do:

```
string path = (string) ((ListViewItem)temp.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
```

You can also check if the path is a directory and act accordingly.